# How to print (on ng-click) an item of a ng-repeat outside the loop?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple array of objects `{name,age}` (see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/par2nrd4/2/)). I use an ng-repeat to print all the names and I would like to print, outside the ng-repeat loop, the age of the name on which I click.

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="friend in myData.friends" ng-click="myData.doClick($index)">{{friend.name}}</li>
</ul>
<p>Age :</p>
<p>{{}}</p>
</div>
<script>
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.friends = [{ name: "Al",age:26}, { name: "Mike",age:21}, { name: "Brian",age:46} ];
    $scope.myData.doClick = function(item) {
    }
} );
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `$index`, you should pass the object itself, `friend`, then you can read his information.

Quick refactoring: http://jsfiddle.net/par2nrd4/4/

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for you....

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="MyController" >
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="friend in myData.friends" ng-click="myData.doClick(friend.name)">{{friend.name}}</li>
</ul>
<p>Age :</p>
<p>{{ageval}}</p>
</div>
<script>
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.friends = [{ name: "Al",age:26}, { name: "Mike",age:21}, { name: "Brian",age:46} ];
    $scope.myData.doClick = function(item) {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.myData.friends.length; i++) {
            if (item == $scope.myData.friends[i]["name"]) {
                $scope.ageval = $scope.myData.friends[i]["age"];
            }
        }
    }
} );
</script>
</body>
```